# View Apple Music play history (playlists) from radio stations like Beats 1?

Tags: apple-music

I missed "liking" a song that was playing on Beats 1. Now I'm trying to see what songs were played previously in the Beats 1 radio station (like a playlist history). Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score -1):

Hej m8, check this instruction: http://www.imore.com/how-use-next-apples-new-music-app#history

Comment: Please pull the relevant information out of that article and add it to your answer (of course, link to your source). We do this here because links occasionally go away, and then nobody can find your answer!